# Set width of LaTeX float # in List of X

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, floats

Using the LaTeX [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float), I've created a new float:

```
\newfloat{schema}{htb}{los}[chapter]
\floatname{schema}{{Schema}}
```

The list of schemas at the beginning of my document is created with the command

```
\listof{schema}{List of Schema}
```

My problem is that LaTeX isn't reserving as much space as I'd like for the schema number in the List of Schemas.  When a schema number consists of three digits, like

```
\numberline {5.14}
```

then the last digit of this number comes quite close to the first letter of the caption of the schema.  (In fact, if the number has four digits, it can actually overlap the caption.)

I tried to come up with a solution using the [`tocloft` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft), but I couldn't figure out how to make that work in conjunction with the `\newfloat` command--it sounds like I should tell `tocloft` to change a `numwidth` variable associated with my 'schema' float, but I have not been able to figure out what the name of that variable is (it's not `schemanumwidth` or anything else obvious).  It may be that `tocloft` just doesn't know about floats created with the `float` package's `\newfloat` command.

I finally came up with a dirty hack:

```
\let\orignumberline\numberline
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{\orignumberline{#1}\hspace{1em}}
```

This wouldn't be too bad if it affected only my List of Schemas, but of course it also affects the chapter and section #s in the ToC, the table #s in the ToT, etc., all of which had perfectly adequate spacing before (and now look a little odd with a too-wide spacing).

This seems like the sort of thing that ought to work out of the box: if I define a new float, and create a list of them, then LaTeX ought to leave enough space between the float # and the float caption in the listing of this float.  Am I overlooking something obvious?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291566/set-width-of-latex-float-in-list-of-x?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com). Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float) defines the `\listof` command the does some float checks, sets up the "List of Floats" parameters and calls `\@starttoc`. A manual definition of the specific "List of Floats" in this case is possible:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\listofschemas}{%
  \@namedef{l@schema}{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{4em}}
  \float@listhead{List of Schemas}%
  \begingroup\setlength{\parskip}{\z@}%
    \@starttoc{\@nameuse{ext@schema}}%
  \endgroup%
}%
\makeatother
```

The most important part here is

```
\@namedef{l@schema}{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{4em}}
```

that uses

```
\@dottedtocline{<seclevel>}{<indent>}{<numwidth>}
```

The default for `<numwidth>` is `2.3em`, giving the width of the sectional heading in the "List of Floats". I've modified this to `4em` to make it almost twice as wide.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{float}% http://ctan.org/pkg/float
\newfloat{schema}{htb}{los}[chapter]
\floatname{schema}{Schema}%
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\listofschemas}{%
  \@namedef{l@schema}{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{4em}}
  \float@listhead{List of Schemas}%
  \begingroup\setlength{\parskip}{\z@}%
    \@starttoc{\@nameuse{ext@schema}}%
  \endgroup%
}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listofschemas
\chapter{A chapter} \lipsum[1]
\begin{figure} \centering test \caption{A figure} \end{figure}% FIGURE
\begin{schema} \centering test \caption{A schema} \end{schema}% SCHEMA
\begin{figure} \centering test \caption{A figure} \end{figure}% FIGURE
\begin{figure} \centering test \caption{A figure} \end{figure}% FIGURE
\begin{schema} \centering test \caption{A schema} \end{schema}% SCHEMA
\chapter{Another chapter} \lipsum[2]
\begin{figure} \centering test \caption{A figure} \end{figure}% FIGURE
\begin{schema} \centering test \caption{A schema} \end{schema}% SCHEMA
\begin{figure} \centering test \caption{A figure} \end{figure}% FIGURE
\begin{figure} \centering test \caption{A figure} \end{figure}% FIGURE
\begin{schema} \centering test \caption{A schema} \end{schema}% SCHEMA
\end{document}
```

This will be specific to the "List of Schemas".

---

If you wish to add a vertical gap between entries in the "List of Schemas" to separate schemas by chapter, add

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\preto\chapter{\float@addtolists{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}}%
\makeatother
```

to your document preamble. The [`etoolbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) is capable of patching commands; in this case, prepending some content before `\chapter` via `\preto\chapter{<stuff>}`. Here `<stuff>` adds up to a `10pt` vertical gap between all the defined "List of..." structures (except LoF and LoT). `\addvspace` takes care of only adding `10pt` if needed. For example, if you have a chapter without any schemas in it, you don't want the gap between chapter-wise schemas in the "List of Schemas" to be `20pt`. Using the above MWE together with the `etoolbox` addition yields:

[image]

Comment: Wow, 7:30 AM on Monday, about eight hours after I posted--and it works perfectly!  Thank you!!!

Comment: @MikeMaxwell: Note that there is no gap between the schemas from one chapter to the next (as is the case with regular figures/tables). This is also possible. Regardless, if this answered your question, consider upvoting (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it; you need 15 reputation points before you can upvote) and accepting it (by clicking on the checkmark).

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "gap between the schemas"--they're numbered consecutively starting from 1 within each chapter, which is what I wanted.  And I "upvoted" and check-marked it :-)

Comment: @MikeMaxwell: There's a small gap between the figures in each *chapter* of the LoF (between Figure 1.3 and 2.1 in my example), while there's nothing between the schemas for each *chapter*. That is the gap I'm referring to.

Comment: "Note that there is no gap between the schemas from one chapter to the next... This is also possible."  I thought I could figure this out, but no soap.  I presume it would be done with a command like "\float@addtolists{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}" (copied from the 'floats' documentation), but I can't figure out where to put this--depending on where I put it, it either has no visible effect, or causes an error.

Comment: I found the solution, which I'm recording here:
`\let\oldchap=\chapter
\renewcommand*{\chapter}{%
  \secdef{\Chap}{\ChapS}%
}
\newcommand{\ChapS}[1]{\oldchap*{#1}}
\newcommand{\Chap[2]}[]{\oldchap[#1]{#2}\float@addtolists{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}}`
It uses code for redefining the chapter from http://wiki.lyx.org/Tips/ModifyChapterEtc, which I don't pretend to completely understand.

Comment: @MikeMaxwell: I've updated my answer with a suggestion in terms of added a vertical chapter-wise gap in your "List of Schemas". Rather not redefine the `\chapter` command; not only is it cleaner, but it is safer as well, since other elements of the document might use `\chapter`. Patching via [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) is sufficient.